# populating each character to std::vector <char *> from console application

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a C++ Console based application which collects and populates each characters typed in the console to a `std::vector <char *>` asynchronously without blocking the user
Can anyone help me in how to populate each char entered in `std::vector <char *>` .

John

Comment: why asynchronously? time taken to insert a character into vector is very small compared to the time taken for the user to type the input.

Comment: Use std::vector<char> instead.

Comment: I was actually going to help you, but then I realized you'd omitted a template parameter, so I went and fixed your formatting for you, and now the question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do it asynchronously.

```
std::vector<char> foo;

void populate(char a)
{
    foo.push_back(a);
}
```

Comment: But,I have requirement I should populate the vector in one thread and then should iterate and print the same vector in another thread,how can i don it critical section

Comment: @john: The answers to that vary widely depending on the thread library you're using. I suggest you modify your original question, stating the requirements, and what tools (compiler, libraries, etc.) you're using. Oh, and I already added the `homework` tag to your question, so that people will give you nudges into the right direction instead of pasting code.